# PHP Oracle Query Data based on Array in table

Tags: php, oracle

I have an oracle sql statement.

table data like this:

```
FORM_NO | PART_NO | CHUTTER_ID
1       | ABC     | 1,3,9,12,15
```

I have PHP variable

```
$get_q = "3";
```

Now I want to query:

```
$q = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE CHUTTER_ID IN '$get_q'");
oci_execute($q);
```

The result of query is empty.

Anyone know, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the test like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE ',' || CHUTTER_ID || ',' LIKE '%,$get_q,%'"
```

This appends commas to the value of CUTTER_ID so that it becomes something like:

```
,1,3,9,12,15,
```

Then it checks that the above matches this pattern:

```
%,3,%
```

where a `%` represents 0 to any number of characters. The additional commas are needed to make sure also 1 and 15 would be found with this method.

#### About your original query

Your query is invalid because the `IN` operator requires the right argument to be a bracketed list, like so `(3)`, without quotes. But even if you would do that, you would get this expression:

```
CUTTER_ID IN (3)
```

which is like saying:

```
'1,3,9,12,15' IN (3)
```

But that does not make sense. You'd want to test the opposite:

```
3 in (1,3,9,12,15)
```

But alas, the database field `CUTTER_ID` is not suitable for such a construct. Luckily, the alternative with `LIKE` can work.

#### SQL Injection

Please note that if the value '3' in your example is derived from user input, then your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To avoid this, bind the value via  `oci_bind_by_name`, like this:

```
$q = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM tb_test 
                     WHERE ',' || CHUTTER_ID || ',' LIKE '%,' || :p1 || ',%'");
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $get_q);
oci_execute($q);
```

#### Database design

Finally, a list of values in one database field is not a sign of a good database model. This is an example of a database that is not normalised. It does not even meet the [first normalisation form](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php).

If you have control over the database design, please consider changing it as suggested in the article linked above. It will improve the speed of your queries.